# Images resize as the window resize

Tags: jquery, html

I have some images in my html dom. The images are

```
  <div id="page">
    <div class="image-gallery">
      <img src="images/imagewords.jpeg" alt="sec">
      <img src="images/images.jpeg" alt="thi">
      <img src="images/imagedss.jpeg" alt="fou">
      <img src="images/imrtages.jpeg" alt="fiv">
      <img src="images/nasa-images.jpeg" alt="six">
      <img src="images/pre-raphaelite-galleries-vi.jpg" alt="sev">
      <img src="images/websitfe-design.jpg" alt="nin">
    </div>
  </div><!-- #page-->
```

now i want to resize all the images when i resize the window. Is there any plugin in jquery or tutorial in jQuery. Please help me to resize the images.

Answer (score 0):

Resize them how? To a fixed size? To a percentage of the window width? To a percentage of the container? Generally, you don't need JS for that, just define the widths as a percentage.

For example:

```
.image-gallery {
    width: 100%;
}
    .image-gallery img {
        width: 20%; /* or whatever width you want here. */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

css :

```
img{max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

check this:
source: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries

Answer (score 0):

Try it like:

**CSS**

```
.image-gallery{width:50%;}
.image-gallery img{width:100%;}
```

**HTML**

```
   <div id="page">
    <div class="image-gallery">
      <img src="images/imagewords.jpeg" alt="sec">
      <img src="images/images.jpeg" alt="thi">
      <img src="images/imagedss.jpeg" alt="fou">
      <img src="images/imrtages.jpeg" alt="fiv">
      <img src="images/nasa-images.jpeg" alt="six">
      <img src="images/pre-raphaelite-galleries-vi.jpg" alt="sev">
      <img src="images/websitfe-design.jpg" alt="nin">
    </div>
  </div><!-- #page-->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(window).resize(function () {
    var h = parseInt($(window).height(), 10);
    var w = parseInt($(window).width(), 10);
    $("img").css({
        'width': w,
        'height': h
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This jQuery plugin does what you want:
http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/

Alternativly you can access the window size with this code:

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height(),
    windowWidth = $(window).width();
```